# Why is the "apt" command not found?

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, software-installation

```
sudo: apt: command not found
```

What does this error mean? The `apt` command is not working, and I've lost the Software Center.

Comment: You need to use`apt-get` in the command instead of `apt`.

Comment: To people voting to close this: This is definitely a real question, and there is already enough information for it to be answered. We should not close this question. I'll post a CW answer that include information others have said.

Comment: I had the same problem, since I wanted to use apt-get to install something. It seems 'yum' was the default package manager in my case, which I should have used instead. Reference: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33688/installing-git-sudo-apt-get-command-not-found

Answer (score 13):

> Starting in Ubuntu 14.04, there *is* a command in Ubuntu called just
>   `apt`, which didn't exist when this question was originally asked. The
>   `apt` command provides a convenient subset of the functionality of
>   various other `apt-` commands (e.g., `apt-get`, `apt-cache`), with
>   colorized display and progress bars. Although the `apt` command does
>   *not* support all the same actions and options as `apt-get`, it may often be used in place of `apt-get`. **See [Fsando's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/563100/22949) for
>   details.**

APT is a suite of utilities, including a database of information about what packages are available from where.

APT is not a single command. Rather, it provides several commands.

The most commonly used APT command is `apt-get`. That's what you should probably be using.

To update information about what packages are available and from where (which you should do before attempting to upgrade or install any packages with `apt-get`), run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

To upgrade packages (i.e., "update your system"), run:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

To upgrade packages, including packages that require uninstalled packages to be installed, or installed packages to be removed, run this (but be careful--it's best to pay attention to what will be added or removed):

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

To install one or more packages, run this, replacing `...` with the list of packages you want to install (if you want to install more than one package, put spaces between the package names):

```
sudo apt-get install ...
```

To remove one or more packages (i.e., to uninstall it), run:

```
sudo apt-get remove ...
```

To remove a package and also remove its systemwide configuration files (but not its per-user configuration files, which reside in users' home directories), run:

```
sudo apt-get purge ...
```

To remove packages that were installed automatically because other packages needed them, but which now are no longer needed, run:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

To do that, and also remove their global configuration files"

```
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove
```

To reinstall a package, run:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install ...
```

To reinstall a package and delete its systemwide configuration files while doing so:

```
sudo apt-get --purge --reinstall install ...
```

To delete cached package installer (`.deb`) files (which does *not* remove any packages, but will make it so they have to be fetched over the network again to be reinstalled):

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

To deleted cached package installer files, but *only* for packages that are unlikely to be needed again (i.e., those that are so old they've been removed from the servers, as of last time `sudo apt-get update` was run):

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

That was just a brief overview. It does not capture all possible uses of `apt-get`, plus there are a number of other utilities provided in the APT suite, such as `apt-cache` for examining information about installed and available packages.

You can learn more by reading the [`apt-get`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/apt-get.8.html) and [`apt`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/apt.8.html) manual pages.

Comment: You could also add info about creating a bash alias for apt..

Answer (score 2):

There is no command just `apt` for that you've gotten this error. The list that 
**Eliah Kagan**  provided you with can be a resource for using **APT** utilities but as answer for your question the problem in your writing of the command.

Answer (score 2):

apt is an actual command in 14.04 and it relates to apt-get and friends as can be seen here:

```
:~# apt
apt 1.0.1ubuntu2 for amd64 compiled on Oct 28 2014 20:55:14
Usage: apt [options] command

CLI for apt.
Basic commands:
list - list packages based on package names
search - search in package descriptions
show - show package details

update - update list of available packages

install - install packages
remove  - remove packages

upgrade - upgrade the system by installing/upgrading packages
full-upgrade - upgrade the system by removing/installing/upgrading packages

edit-sources - edit the source information file
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to run apt-get?

Try running

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Let me know how that works.